# Не отображается RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Пытаюсь разобраться с RecyclerView, но ничего не получается, экран пуст.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ItemAdapter adapter;

        ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
        myList.add("Milk");
        myList.add("Lime");
        myList.add("Meat");
        myList.add("Candys");

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        adapter = new ItemAdapter(this, myList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**ItemAdapter**

```
   public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ViewHolder> {

   private ArrayList<String> myList;
   private LayoutInflater myLayout;

   public ItemAdapter(Context vContext, ArrayList<String> myList) {
       this.myList = myList;
       this.myLayout = LayoutInflater.from(vContext);
   }

   @NonNull
   @Override
   public ItemAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       View view = myLayout.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
       return new ViewHolder(view);
   }

   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
       holder.textView.setText(myList.get(position));
   }

   @Override
   public int getItemCount() {
       return myList.size();
   }

   public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
       TextView textView;
       public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
           super(itemView);
           textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_Name);
       }
   }
}
```

**item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:text="TextView1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
       android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
       android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
       tools:listitem="@layout/item"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы забыли добавить `LayoutManager`. Добавьте его после инициализации `RecyclerView`:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Все работает.